# Any recommendations for handling JSON files in Perl?

Tags: json, macos, perl, gcc, clang

I tried install JSON-Parse-3.0 (from CPAN) for Perl on my OSx laptop.
However, when I try to compile it (following a perl Makefile.PL) I get:

```
# make
/usr/bin/clang -c   -pipe -Os -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp    -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/opt/local/include -O3   -DVERSION=\"0.30\" -DXS_VERSION=\"0.30\"  "-I/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   Json3.c
In file included from Json3.xs:2:
/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/perl.h:583:11: fatal error:    'sys/types.h' file not found
#       include <sys/types.h>
            ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Json3.o] Error 1
```

I can't find the missing types.h file.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this, or alternatively, what other perl package to use for parsing JSON files? This JSON-Parse is the one that keeps coming up.

EDIT: Changing clang to gcc gives different errors:

```
   Json3.c:313: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
   Json3.c:313: error: invalid type argument of ‘unary *’
```

Comment: Why are you not using the `cpan` tool?

Comment: And also, perhaps, why not install the `JSON` package?

Comment: Module recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: @TLP I used the cpan tool, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: What happens if you try to install `JSON`?

Comment: Or I should say, are you sure you can install anything at all? Perhaps something went wrong when you installed Perl.

Answer (score 1):

The top level [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) file is the most popular that I've found, is well supported and hasn't failed me yet.  Most importantly, it operates with more than one backend and there are two options to install with it: a [Pure Perl (PP)](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON/backportPP.pm) one and a (obviously faster) [XS](http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/JSON-XS-3.01/XS.pm) based one.